# How to place Intent code in another class and call where neccessary in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i pass Intent from one activity to another but i want to place Intent code in another class and call it where neccessary . How can I do that

code:-

```
Intent changePassword = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CChangePasswordScreen.class);
                    startActivity(changePassword);
```

Comment: As you can see you need application context, so as long as you pass context to your class it should work. Im sure where is answers on this topic already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use intent from any class you must reached the `Context` which is intent in.

Try like this;

```
public class YourClass {
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent intent;    

    public YourClass(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
    }

    // Some other methods...

}
```